# In WinUI 3, CommunityToolkit.WinUi, DataGridComboBoxColumn there is a Binding problem

Tags: binding, datagrid, winui-3, windows-community-toolkit, datagridcomboboxcolumn

In my view model class, there is an `[ObservableProperty]` called `EmployeesList` of type `ObservableCollection<Employee>`.

Similarly there is another `[ObservableProperty]` called `LeavesList` of type `ObservableCollection<Leave>`.

Both are populated asynchronously using a service.

On my page there is a DataGrid that is bound to the `LeavesList` (`ItemsSource="{x:Bind viewModel.LeavesList}`).

One of its columns is a `DataGridComboBoxColumn` represents the name of the employee.

As usual the `ItemsSource` of the `DataGridComboBoxColumn` is bound to the employees list.

The value of the `DataGridComboBoxColumn` is bound to a property of Leave namely `EmployeeId`.

The exact problem is originated form the fact that `Leave.EmployeeId` is actually an FK that points to `Employee.Id` but the documentation states that these **MUST** be of the same name for the binding to work.

[Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/datagrid_guidance/datagrid_basics#datagridcomboboxcolumn)

I am not in the business to change model classes just to please XAML front end.

So what I did is a dirty and disgusting solution which is to map `ObservableCollection<Employee>` to a new `ObservableCollection<TempEmployeeClassThatHasEmployeeIdInsteadOfId>` just to rename the primary key name to `EmployeeId` instead of `Id` to match the FK in the `Leave` model class.

Is there a cleaner way to do it using XALM ? or C# in the view model or somewhere else that is reusable, without temporary objects and workarounds?

```xml
<controls:DataGridComboBoxColumn
    Binding="{Binding EmployeeId, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    DisplayMemberPath="Name"
    Header="Employee Name"
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind viewModel.TempEmployeeListWithIdReWrittenToEmployeeIdJustToMatchLeave_EmployeeId, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    Tag="Employee Name" />
```

I need to circumvent the requirement:

> The ItemsSource elements of the column must have at least one property with the same name as the elements of the ItemsSource belonging to the DataGrid itself.

(from [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/datagrid_guidance/datagrid_basics#datagridcomboboxcolumn))

Comment: Can you post code around your ViewModel?

Comment: No code to post,  as ViewModels has only one line declaration per a property as shown in the question.

Comment: Not an answer but "I am not in the business to change model classes just to please XAML" is why the MVVM "pseudo pattern" was introduced 15 years ago:  Not really to *invent* something new, but a big hack to be able to just work with XAML and it's very special binding features. You have XAML (the View), your Model (suposedly independant from XML/WinUI3/UWP/WPF but that's in general not very possible) and then an intermediary model called VM full of INotifyPropertyChanged,  ObservableCollection, that ties all that together. Binding V to M is often possible but only if M is designed for V.

Comment: Oh, I hit a wall here, simply it is an incomplete product pushed by Microsoft, I don’t think there is a solution here

Comment: Can you explain the minimal look of how your DataGrid should look like?

Comment: The issue is generic actually The ItemsSource elements of the column must have at least one property with the same name as the elements of the ItemsSource belonging to the DataGrid itself. The problem is in the MUST, because it means model layer has to follow a rule dictated by UI layer, I simply solved it by switching to a third party Data Grid.